# How to deploy a Scala/Akka application?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm developing an application which subscribes to Instagram real times updates(Users). I need to provide an urlcallback in order to receive the users updates.

```
 Curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
 -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
 -F 'object=user' \
 -F 'aspect=media' \
 -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
 -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

Now my application is running on localhost.
How can I deploy a Scala application in order to have a real urlcallback?

Comment: You could create deb, rpm, docker package using  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager and install your application to your server.

Comment: You can build a standalone / normal JAR as well, and launch it with java -jar...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to deploy your Scala application. If it is a web application, then you can package that application in a .war file and deploy on any machine which has a web server.The another option is you can use an AWS EC2 instance or AWS Elasticbeanstalk service to deploy your .war file.In any case,your urlCallback would be "http://:/"

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure sbt-native-packager at your project by modifying build.sbt and project/plugins.sbt files.
2. Build your application using sbt-native-packager, either on your local machine or on a build server like Jenkins. This creates a zip, docker image, rpm or Debian. In case you run an Debian type server like Ubuntu, the Debian file would be the easiest choice.
3. Upload the just created file to your server, using for example scp or rsync. The files created by the build are located in the target directory of your project.
4. Install your app on your server. In case you are running a Debian type server like Ubuntu and created a Debian file at the build process, a simple dpkg -i  will install your app.
5. In your case you should install a proxy like nginx and configure your app as an nginx backend. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Answer (score -1):

you could use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, make a fat jar with "sbt assembly" in the console  and then do java -jar aplication.jar.